# Trying to detect encoding of Russian text-and read as string

Tags: c#, .net

I am received some Russian text over network. Here is dump of those bytes:

When I am trying to interpret this as ASCII string of course it doesn't work. Neither this seems to be a UTF8 encoding. Can someone help how to read these bytes in *C# as string*? (you can see debugger shows the letters next to them)

[image]

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: @StepUp: Why code? Code can be as simple as calling ASCIIEncoding.GetString on this byte array or using UTF8 encoding instead in former call

Comment: [Code page 1251](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc195053.aspx)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Seems like, how would I interpret this as string in C# then?

Comment: do you want to convert Russian text to ASCII?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Strangely there is C++ code which correctly reads this as string - I need to check how it works

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: How to read this as string in C#?

Comment: yeah, Russian language uses UTF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like cyrillic, codepage 1251.

```
var bytes = new byte[]
{
    210, 240, 224, 237, 231, 224, 234, 246, 232, 255, 32, 237, 229, 32, 236, 238, 230, 229, 242, 32, 225, 251, 242
};
var text = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);
// text = "Транзакция не может быт"
```

Not sure if there's a better way to figure it out than looping over the available codepages and see what looks looks right:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(i).GetString(bytes));
        Console.WriteLine("Encoding: {0}", i);
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(i).EncodingName);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Cyrillic similar to ASCII for letters having code below 128?

Comment: There's a long somewhat complex history as to why text encodings are they way they are. Read [Joel Spolsky's introductionary article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) explaining the differences.

Comment: I will but: "Is this Cyrillic similar to ASCII for letters having code below 128?"

Comment: Most (if not all) codepages are identical below 128, and language specific characters are located at higher code points. So yes, Cyrillic is identical to ASCII below 128.

Comment: Hm it seems in my app I need to use 1251 now.. I was using ASCII.... it won't make difference for english letters anyway right?

Comment: Correct, [cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) contains all the english letters at the expected code points.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you know where you get the text in most cases you have some information about the encoding, so you can simply use the class "Encoding", select the appropriate encoding and call the GetString

For example so `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`
or so `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString()`

If you do not have any information about encoding, then it is a different task, you have to look for some algorithm for encoding detection

Comment: it seems in this case it is Code page 1251

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "Привет, люди!";
var utf8bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
var win1251Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"), utf8bytes);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"foo.txt", win1251Bytes);
```

Comment: Is this Cyrillic similar to ASCII for letters having code below 128?

Comment: @user200312 yes, it is similar